# Compress a file into different parts in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, zip, compression

Is it a way in Python (2.7 preferably) to compress a file in several equally-sized `.zip` files??

The result would be something like: (lets assume 200MB selected and compressing a file of 1100MB)

```
compressed_file.zip.001 (200MB)
compressed_file.zip.002 (200MB)
compressed_file.zip.003 (200MB)
compressed_file.zip.004 (200MB)
compressed_file.zip.005 (200MB)
compressed_file.zip.006 (100MB)
```

Comment: The question is, what have you tried in order to do something like that?

Comment: @user5173426 checked on available docs : https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html nothing found so far

Comment: it might not even be possible, im also fine with that.

Comment: Hmm, `ZipFile` can use a file-like object for IO... so implement one that handles the file rotataion? Not sure if it's worth the effort tho.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can do it in shell command. Somthing like

```
gzip -c /path/to/your/large/file | split -b 150000000 - compressed.gz
```

and you can execute shell from python.

Regards

Ganesh J

Comment: hi thanks, I think in the back of my head i read about this one before. I was more curious about any pythonic approach.

Comment: accepted because I ended up using a variation of this answer, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**NB**: This is based on assumption that the result is just a chopped up ZIP file without any extra headers or anything.

If you check the docs, [`ZipFile`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/zipfile.html) can be passed a [file-like](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-file-objects) object to use for the I/O. Hence, we should be able to give it our own object which implements the necessary subset of the protocol, and which splits the output into multiple files.

As it turns out, we only need to implement 3 functions:

- [`tell()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.tell) -- just return number of bytes written so far
- [`write(str)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.write) -- write to file until max capacity, once full open a new file, repeat until all data written
- [`flush()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.flush) -- flush the currently open file

### Prototype Script

```
import random
import zipfile


def get_random_data(length):
    return "".join([chr(random.randrange(256)) for i in range(length)])


class MultiFile(object):
    def __init__(self, file_name, max_file_size):
        self.current_position = 0
        self.file_name = file_name
        self.max_file_size = max_file_size
        self.current_file = None        
        self.open_next_file()

    @property
    def current_file_no(self):
        return self.current_position / self.max_file_size

    @property
    def current_file_size(self):
        return self.current_position % self.max_file_size

    @property
    def current_file_capacity(self):
        return self.max_file_size - self.current_file_size

    def open_next_file(self):
        file_name = "%s.%03d" % (self.file_name, self.current_file_no + 1)
        print "* Opening file '%s'..." % file_name
        if self.current_file is not None:
            self.current_file.close()
        self.current_file = open(file_name, 'wb')

    def tell(self):
        print "MultiFile::Tell -> %d" % self.current_position
        return self.current_position

    def write(self, data):
        start, end = 0, len(data)
        print "MultiFile::Write (%d bytes)" % len(data)
        while start < end:
            current_block_size = min(end - start, self.current_file_capacity)
            self.current_file.write(data[start:start+current_block_size])
            print "* Wrote %d bytes." % current_block_size
            start += current_block_size
            self.current_position += current_block_size
            if self.current_file_capacity == self.max_file_size:
                self.open_next_file()
            print "* Capacity = %d" % self.current_file_capacity

    def flush(self):
        print "MultiFile::Flush"
        self.current_file.flush()


mfo = MultiFile('splitzip.zip', 2**18)

zf = zipfile.ZipFile(mfo,  mode='w', compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)


for i in range(4):
    filename = 'test%04d.txt' % i
    print "Adding file '%s'..." % filename
    zf.writestr(filename, get_random_data(2**17))
```

### Trace Output

```
* Opening file 'splitzip.zip.001'...
Adding file 'test0000.txt'...
MultiFile::Tell -> 0
MultiFile::Write (42 bytes)
* Wrote 42 bytes.
* Capacity = 262102
MultiFile::Write (131112 bytes)
* Wrote 131112 bytes.
* Capacity = 130990
MultiFile::Flush
Adding file 'test0001.txt'...
MultiFile::Tell -> 131154
MultiFile::Write (42 bytes)
* Wrote 42 bytes.
* Capacity = 130948
MultiFile::Write (131112 bytes)
* Wrote 130948 bytes.
* Opening file 'splitzip.zip.002'...
* Capacity = 262144
* Wrote 164 bytes.
* Capacity = 261980
MultiFile::Flush
Adding file 'test0002.txt'...
MultiFile::Tell -> 262308
MultiFile::Write (42 bytes)
* Wrote 42 bytes.
* Capacity = 261938
MultiFile::Write (131112 bytes)
* Wrote 131112 bytes.
* Capacity = 130826
MultiFile::Flush
Adding file 'test0003.txt'...
MultiFile::Tell -> 393462
MultiFile::Write (42 bytes)
* Wrote 42 bytes.
* Capacity = 130784
MultiFile::Write (131112 bytes)
* Wrote 130784 bytes.
* Opening file 'splitzip.zip.003'...
* Capacity = 262144
* Wrote 328 bytes.
* Capacity = 261816
MultiFile::Flush
MultiFile::Tell -> 524616
MultiFile::Write (46 bytes)
* Wrote 46 bytes.
* Capacity = 261770
MultiFile::Write (12 bytes)
* Wrote 12 bytes.
* Capacity = 261758
MultiFile::Write (0 bytes)
MultiFile::Write (0 bytes)
MultiFile::Write (46 bytes)
* Wrote 46 bytes.
* Capacity = 261712
MultiFile::Write (12 bytes)
* Wrote 12 bytes.
* Capacity = 261700
MultiFile::Write (0 bytes)
MultiFile::Write (0 bytes)
MultiFile::Write (46 bytes)
* Wrote 46 bytes.
* Capacity = 261654
MultiFile::Write (12 bytes)
* Wrote 12 bytes.
* Capacity = 261642
MultiFile::Write (0 bytes)
MultiFile::Write (0 bytes)
MultiFile::Write (46 bytes)
* Wrote 46 bytes.
* Capacity = 261596
MultiFile::Write (12 bytes)
* Wrote 12 bytes.
* Capacity = 261584
MultiFile::Write (0 bytes)
MultiFile::Write (0 bytes)
MultiFile::Tell -> 524848
MultiFile::Write (22 bytes)
* Wrote 22 bytes.
* Capacity = 261562
MultiFile::Write (0 bytes)
MultiFile::Flush
```

### Directory Listing

```
-rw-r--r-- 1   2228 Feb 21 23:44 splitzip.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 262144 Feb 22 00:07 splitzip.zip.001
-rw-r--r-- 1 262144 Feb 22 00:07 splitzip.zip.002
-rw-r--r-- 1    582 Feb 22 00:07 splitzip.zip.003
```

### Validation

```
>7z l splitzip.zip.001

7-Zip [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18

Listing archive: splitzip.zip.001

--
Path = splitzip.zip.001
Type = Split
Volumes = 3
----
Path = splitzip.zip
Size = 524870
--
Path = splitzip.zip
Type = zip
Physical Size = 524870

   Date      Time    Attr         Size   Compressed  Name
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
2019-02-22 00:07:34 .....       131072       131112  test0000.txt
2019-02-22 00:07:34 .....       131072       131112  test0001.txt
2019-02-22 00:07:36 .....       131072       131112  test0002.txt
2019-02-22 00:07:36 .....       131072       131112  test0003.txt
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
                                524288       524448  4 files, 0 folders
```